# Why isn't my image being drawn on HTML5 canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, sprite

I'm following the tutorials and setting up my code.. but when I run it I can an error message

"(index):18 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state."

This is my code which Im running in the indexSoccer.html file,

```
    var ctx = document.getElementById("ctx").getContext("2d");

    var Img = {};
    Img.player = new Image();
    Img.player.src = 'images/cat1sprite.png';

    drawPlayer = function(player){
        ctx.save();
        var x = player.x;
        var y = player.y;
        ctx.drawImage(Img.player, x, y);
        ctx.restore();

    }
```

and my directory looks like the following -

[image]

any ideas why?

Comment: “The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state” – https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#img-error

Comment: tried a different file, same error.

Comment: But `<img src="images/cat1sprite.png">` put into the HTML code would show the image …?

Answer (score 6):

Because you try to draw the image before it is loaded.

```
var Img = {};
Img.player = new Image();
Img.player.onload = function() {
  // Try to draw your image only after this function has been called.
  // eg: drawPlayer(Player1);
}
Img.player.src = 'images/cat1sprite.png';
```

Also, make sure to look into the console for errors (in case the image path is wrong).

Comment: @joe And you don't get any other `erros`? Are you sure the error isn't triggered somewhere else in your code? When do you call the `drawPlayer` function?

Comment: in a setInterval function

Comment: And you create the interval after the image loads, inside the onload callback, right?

Comment: I'm getting this problem *after* the image has already been successfully drawn to the canvas a few times, so in my case it's not that it hasn't finished loading.

Comment: I'm also having a problem after the image is loaded. My code is specifically checking img.complete and then getting this exception when drawing the image. It only happens occasionally.

Comment: @CpnCrunch When do you check for img.complete? Maybe you check it before the image is finished loading.

Comment: @XCS: the documentation says (about complete): "A Boolean value which is true if the image has completely loaded; otherwise, the value is false."

Comment: @CpnCrunch Yes, but that value changes (it's false before it's loaded and true after). You should post your code in a new question

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is ctx.save(); ctx.restore(); you don't need them, try without them like in [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_drawimage.asp). Also check the path of the image and that the image is correct (maybe you have a png called .jpg or something like this)

Comment: Have you checked the image file ?

Comment: Mumble mumble, maybe Cristy is right the problem is that you are trying to draw the image before it's loaded