# I'm trying to create a simple Google dino game but I'm only getting the title of the game and a gray box

Tags: javascript, image-processing, drawing

I'm new to JavaScript and I'm trying to create a simple Google dino game but I have been facing problems in that I can't see the dinosaur nor the cacti. Upon opening the live server for the HTML file and get into the new window for the game, I clicked inspect on the window to see what exactly the error was at. The errors are found on the lines in which I use context.drawImage as shown below:

```
//dino
    velocityY += gravity; //velocity of jumping upwards weighed down with gravity
    dino.y = Math.min(dino.y + velocityY, dinoY); // applies gravity to current dino.y, so that dino doesn't exceed ground level
    context.drawImage(dinoImg, dino.x, dino.y, dino.width, dino.height);

    //cactus
    for (let i = 0; i <= cactusArray.length; i++) {
        cactusArray[i].x += velocityX;
        context.drawImage(cactusArray[i].img, cactusArray[i].x, cactusArray[i].y, cactusArray[i].width, cactusArray[i].height);

        if (detectCollision(dino, cactusArray[i])) {
            gameOver = true;
            dinoImg.src = "./img/dino-dead.png";
            dinoImg.onload = function() { 
                context.drawImage(dinoImg, dino.x, dino.y, dino.width, dino.height);
            }
        }
    }
```

In addition, these errors only occurred in function update(){...}

I have already ensured that all the images are placed correctly into the same folder. Moreover, I placed console.log("Dino image loaded"); the line before context.drawImage. Even then, the message was not logged, so I do believe that there might be an issue with the image path or loading process.

Comment: What are the errors? Please update your question including them.

Comment: Sorry for not being detailed enough. What I am trying to do is to display particular images into the window that is meant to play out my Google Dino game. However, no image of the dinosaur nor the cacti showed up, leaving me with much concern of what exactly was the error. Upon inspecting that window, I got the following:  

Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state. 

What does this error even signify, exactly?

Comment: Thank you very much for the update! Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36530321/9997212) help you in any way?